# Need help with a certain integrating technique

Tags: integration

How do I integrate this?

$$\frac{\text{d}P}{\text{d}t} = \frac{(r(t) - B)}{z} \cdot P(t) + c\cdot w$$

The t is just the top limit in the integral.

Let me be more specific. I have this:

$$\frac{dP}{dt} = g(t)P(t) + k$$ where $k$ is a constant and $g(t)$ is any function of $t$, is to put all $P(t)$ on the same side and multiply as such:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dP}{dt} - g(t)P(t) &=& K\\
e^{\int^t-g(s)ds}\frac{dP}{dt} - g(t)e^{\int^t-g(s)ds}P(t) &=& Ke^{\int^t-g(s)ds}\\
\frac{d}{dt}\Big(e^{-\int^t g(s)ds}P(t)\Big) &=& Ke^{\int^t-g(s)ds}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: What is the lower limit?

Comment: Which function is $g$?

Comment: I edited my post to be more specific

Comment: Check most recent update

Comment: So you just actually need help solving this differential equation using an integration factor?

Comment: Correct. I am not sure what to do at this point, and any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you just want to solve the differential equation that you stated).

Note: it was stated in the comments that it may be assumed that $r(t)=at$

$g(t)=\frac{at-B}{z}$

$\dfrac{dP}{dt} = g(t)P(t) + k \iff \dfrac{dP}{dt}-gP=k$

Use $e^{-\int g dt}=e^{-\int\frac{at-B}{z}dt}=e^{\frac{Bt-\frac{a}{2}t^2}{z}}$ as your integrating factor.

Then $e^{\frac{Bt-\frac{a}{2}t^2}{z}}\dfrac{dP}{dt} -\frac{at-B}{z}e^{\frac{Bt-\frac{a}{2}t^2}{z}} P=ke^{\frac{Bt-\frac{a}{2}t^2}{z}}$

Or equivalently, $\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(e^{\frac{Bt-\frac{a}{2}t^2}{z}}P \right)=ke^{\frac{Bt-\frac{a}{2}t^2}{z}}$,

From here you would need to integrate on both sides, but that doesn't seem like a walk in the park (the expression on the right hand side could in fact only be expressed in terms of error functions).

Comment: Thank you for the help! But how do I integrate? that was my question from the beginning

Comment: @JacksonHart The thing is, we don't really know much about your function $g$, in fact, not even every general function $g$ is integrable. So I'm not sure if it is possible to work this out further (if you would give me a specific function $g$ I could do it, but that's not the case here).

Comment: If you scroll to the very very top I added the function. You can see what I called "g"

Comment: @JacksonHart Ah ok, the text is slightly confusing because later on you say that $g$ is any general function of $t$. Are $B$ and $z$ constants?

Comment: yes but r(t) is not

Comment: @JacksonHart Since $r(t)$ is still a general function of $t$, I think there isn't really a point in working this out further then still, I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh wow my mistake. I can assume r(t) = -a*t

Comment: @JacksonHart That changes everything. Give me a moment.

Comment: It looks good for the most part, though r(t) = neg(a*t) I think you thought it was positive

Comment: Would changing it to what it should be, negative(a*t) help things?

Comment: @JacksonHart I think I misread. But only a few signs would change (plusses would become minusses and vice versa). That wouldn't make a difference. Since your function $r$ is a linear function of $t$, you will always end up with a factor $e^{t^2}$, which is a non-integrable function (if you exclude error functions).

Comment: would i still use the same integrating factor/

Comment: becuase the diffeq would become + instead of minus

Comment: @JacksonHart Yes, you would. You use this technique since this is a first order differential equation. The fact that this is so, is not dependent on the constants. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First_order_equation

Comment: right, but wouldnt it be dP/dt + g(t)P(t)

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that, no matter what the function $g(t)$ is, (so also no matter what sign it has) this remains a first order linear diff eq.

Comment: Right, I understand. I was not sure if this change would result in a solution not involving the error function

Comment: Woudlnt the exp cancel? Just the part that comes to outside would still be there?

Comment: I just realized something. We do not need to use integrating factor since I can express g(t) in terms of -at correct?

Comment: @JacksonHart No and no. It is still a function of $t$. Last thing I'm gonna say about it.